# asp.net session timeout on lost connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, timeout

I have an intranet page which needs to not time out (indefinitely) and I'm using JS to keep it alive that way.

But I am having one issue that happens when the user loses the connection (happens frequently due to to going in and out of wifi range) the session times out then.

How can I keep the session up/refresh it if that happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about increase the session time out on web.config ?

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
     <sessionState timeout="120"></sessionState>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout.aspx

Other possible way is to make your database, connected with the user cookie, and use your "custom session" data that are totally connected with your users.

Comment: I already have that set to a higher number but does not work, once wifi drops it is timed out. How to display a message if the page is timed out, so that the user knows it is?

Comment: @sd_dracula You can do that with ajax call, if the ajax fail to get replay is trigger the fail function, and there you have lost the connection and you can show a message. I mean that you can use ajax to make the call time to time... if this fail you show a message.

Comment: Ok, how to go about doing just that?

Comment: @sd_dracula if you use jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/  if not make a general  javascript ajax call (an example: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp)  Just search for ajax and you find many examples !

Answer (score 0):

Try using in web config if you are using Form Authentication

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms timeout="120"/>
    </authentication>

    <sessionState timeout="120"  />
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

first Sets the session timeout on the server is for all session 
Rather than a single Session

out wifi range is the entire network are broken
so not keep alive

You have to use cookie
use cookie keep alive